# The dual graph of the triangulation

Tags: computational-geometry

I study [Polygon Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) and have an execise.

> Prove or disprove: The dual graph of the triangulation of a monotone polygon is always a chain, that is, any node in this graph has degree at most two.

It seems like the assumption that the dual graph of the triangulation of a monotone polygon is always a chain is false. But how to prove this.

Let's say if it was true, at least one edge of every triangle would be a part of the boundary of the polygon.

I don't have any idea how approach the proof. Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the following serve as a contradiction to the claim? I think a more interesting question would be to prove or disprove that for all monotone polygons there exists a triangulation such that its dual graph is a chain. I'm afraid I do not have anything non-trivial to say about this question.
[image: Contradiction for assertion]

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe there are any rigorous math proof why this is not true

Comment: And by "this" do you mean the original problem you had asked (proving or disproving that dual of any triangulation of a monotone polygon is a chain) or the the one I suggested (proving or disproving that there always exists a triangulation of a monotone polygon such that it's dual is a chain)?

Comment: both of them are interesting ;)

Comment: Well I dont see how showing a producing counterexample is not sufficiently rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to draw a simple y-monotone polygon that has a triangulation which gives a dual that is not a chain. Consider a polygon that looks like a pointy cross. Triangulate it so that each prong is its own triangle. Then there are two vertices that have 3 neighbors.

http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~booth/494-02/homeworks/hw2sol.html 
third question .
pointy cross triangulation will give two vertices with degree 3 - http://www.wikiwand.com/hu/Ny%C3%ADlv%C3%A9g%C5%B1_kereszt